# Set of weak observers in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, observer-pattern, weak-references

I am trying to implement a structure that allows me to store a set of weak observers.

Here is the observer wrapper:

```
public func ==<T: Hashable>(lhs: WeakObserver<T>, rhs: WeakObserver<T>) -> Bool {
  return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

public struct WeakObserver<T where T: AnyObject, T: Hashable> : Hashable {

  private weak var weakObserver : T?

  public init(weakObserver: T){
    self.weakObserver = weakObserver
  }

  public var hashValue : Int {
    return self.weakObserver!.hashValue
  }

}
```

And here is the protocol every observer needs to conform to:

```
public protocol DataModelObserverProtocol : class, Hashable, AnyObject {

  func someFunc()

}
```

Usage:

```
public class DataModel: NSObject, DataModelInterface {

  public var observers = Set<WeakObserver<DataModelObserverProtocol>>()
  //^^^^^ Using 'DataModelObserverProtocol' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'AnyObject' is not supported
}
```

Now, while I am aware that this might be a limitation by Swift itself, I am looking for an alternative solution without having a concrete class as type constraint (if that's not possible, which I am afraid is the case, I'd still love to get alternative "non-hacky" solutions).

Comment: Its worth checking out https://gist.github.com/preble/13ab713ac044876c89b5

Comment: @Kirsteins That actually looks really like what I'm looking for, but it also looks a bit overkill to me (for no obvious reason)

Comment: @Kirsteins Even with the `WeakSet` in place I get the error `Using protocol as a concrete type conforming to protocol is not supported`.

Comment: So really looking for an alternative way of doing it as protocols are not supported as generic constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that there would be better ways of doing this, but it just seems to be too complex for such a simple concept, so I went with a different way:

I just used `NSNotificationCenter` and refactored my code to not have to have a tightly coupled structure, so instead of passing information from the notification, I managed to abstract it in a way that works for me in a way that the notifications do not need to pass arguments to their observers. Due to the fact that the notifications only support passing information via the `userInfo` dictionary I was forced to think around that.

Therefore as I mentioned, I needed a context-decoupled way of doing it. 
This is a very abstract answer, but I think it might help somebody circumvent the issue of having to mess with "dysfunctional generics".

To notify my observers I just register them:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(...)
```

and post notifications without arguments:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification...
```

I had already used the built-in `NSNotificationCenter` in previous projects and I am perfectly aware of its inner workings, but originally I intended to pass information down to the observers, which is why I wanted to restrict it a little more creating a `WeakSet` of sorts.

Again this worked in my case because my observers do not necessarily need to get passed the observable's specifics because it is usually present and accessible by the observers anyway (This is something my structure is providing, it might not be that way in a reader's case). It's hard to explain it so that it makes sense to anybody who reads this, but I was highly discouraged by the `WeakSet` that was proposed, so I went with this. It's more readable (might be less comprehensible to a third party though) and it just seemed more appropriate for my use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Set to hold the references runs a risk that the Set will eventually need to reference an element using its hashValue and, when the weak reference goes nil, the hashValue function will crash.

I couldn't do it with protocols but I found a way to get a similar functionality using a generic function that returns a tuple of functions.

```
struct WeakReference<T>
{
    weak var _reference:AnyObject?
    init(_ object:T) {_reference = object as? AnyObject}
    var reference:T? { return _reference as? T }
}

func weakReferences<T>(_:T.Type) -> ( 
                                     getObjects: ()->[T],
                                     addObject:  (T)->()
                                    )
{  
   var references : [WeakReference<T>] = []

   func getObjects() -> [T]
   { 
      return references.filter({ $0.reference != nil }).map({$0.reference!}) 
   }

   func addObject(object:T)
   { 
      if getObjects().contains({ ($0 as! AnyObject) === (object as! AnyObject) }) 
      { return }
      references.append(WeakReference(object)) 
   } 

  return (getObjects:getObjects, addObject:addObject)   
}

public protocol DataModelObserverProtocol: class, AnyObject
{
   func someFunc() -> String
}

public class DataModel: NSObject, DataModelInterface  
{
   var observers = weakReferences(DataModelObserverProtocol)
}
```

To add observers, you would use:

```
observers.addObject( yourObserver )
```

To iterate through the observers :

```
for observer in observers.objects()
{
   observer.someFunc()
}
```

Both functions are type safe and will only accept/return DataModelObserverProtocol compliant objects

Comment: Type casting of this kind is processed at compile time and merely tells the compiler that we know the variables to be of compatible types.

Comment: The only overhead is a couple of extra "words" of memory for storage and one indirection in the function call.   It is very unlikely to have any meaningful impact on performance.

Comment: I think each `as?` statement is compiled to `if` instruction.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and came up with this surprisingly straightforward solution. Start with a bare bones weak container:

```
class WeakObserverBox {
    weak var unbox: Observer?

    init(_ observer: Observer) {
        self.unbox = observer
    }
}
```

Declare your storage as a dictionary, and use the unique ObjectIdentifier as key. A convenient computed property follows (that one will only contain observers that are alive at the time of calling):

```
var observerDict: [ObjectIdentifier: WeakObserverBox] = [:]
var observers: [Observer] {
    return observerDict.values.compactMap { $0.unbox }
}
```

Operations on all observers are done thru the `observers` array. Adding and removing as follows:

```
func add(_ observer: O) {
    observerDict[ObjectIdentifier(observer)] = WeakObserverBox(observer)
}

func remove(_ observer: Observer) {
    observerDict.removeValue(forKey: ObjectIdentifier(observer))
}
```

BTW, if you need to prune the expired references, this can be done in this getter, or in the add method (or both, depending on your performance considerations), like so:

```
for observerKey in observerDict.keys {
    if observerDict[observerKey]?.unbox == nil {
        observerDict.removeValue(forKey: observerKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty clean and safe approach, I like it.